# Non-static method requires a target; using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have the following query resulting in the error, "Non-static method requires a target".  How do I correct the error and get the data?  There is a DB record.

The goal is to update a record that has a matching ID.

```
public ActionResult 
UpdateApplicantStatus([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, 
Models.ApplicantInfo appInfo)
  {
      var status = DB.dbTable.Where(x => x.applicationID == appInfo.Record.applicationID).Select(x => x.IDstatus).FirstOrDefault();

  }
```

Comment: either appInfo is null or appInfo.Record. This results in this (kinda misleading) error when EF tries to compute the query.

Comment: Try `var appID = appInfo.Record.applicationID;` and use that in your query instead.

Comment: I'll try setting the appID.  Thank you for your suggestion(s).